# Is there a way to revert to Neo4j 2.0.0

Tags: neo4j

Is there a way I can download version 2.0.0 and not 2.0.1.

I need this because apparently in 2.0.1 performance got worst. I tried running the following query (which returns about 6800 items):

```
MATCH (s:S)<-[:B]-(:T)<-[:P]-(ts:TS) where s.Uid = "413dd59c-6b5b-4c69-b6f3-d947758f8af2" return count(ts)
```

With 2.0.0 it takes about at most 1 second to return the count (with all the objects in memory). But for 2.0.1 it just completely times out in the web console UI (for the shell takes about two minutes).

No change to the database was made between the upgrade from 2.0.0 to 2.0.1

Comment: Which version of 2.0 did you use? And do you have an index or unique constraint for :S(Uid) ?

Comment: How big is your total dataset and how did you do the upgrade?

Comment: @MichaelHunger I used the Neo4j Community Edition 2.0.0 for Windows x64 (the installer, not zip distribution). I upgraded by just downloading the new installer and selecting to upgrade.

Comment: @MichaelHunger I have an index on every label on Uid. There is one of type/label S, about 40 of type T, and about 7000 of type TS. It is a tree as there are no cycles.

Comment: @MichaelHunger There are other objects that in total make a huge dataset. But this part of the graph is very simple and they have an index on :S(Uid), :T(Uid), :TS(Uid). Each object also has about 20 properties (varied between integer, strings, and arrays)

Comment: Could you share your dataset with me privately at michael at neotechnology.com I would love to look at this degradation.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

To download Neo4J (zip file) all you need is this URL that you can customize to download the version you prefer:

```
http://www.neo4j.org/download_thanks?edition=community&release=x.y.z&platform=(unix|windows)
```

Then, in your case it will be

```
http://www.neo4j.org/download_thanks?edition=community&release=2.0.0&platform=unix
```

Said that, probably you have to investigate a bit to understand why your performances became so bad with the upgrade because probably downgrade is not the right solution.

Comment: Yes I know this is not a "right solution." But it's the most practical one, as there was not a single change to the database or code, and passing from 1 second to two minutes is very weird, and detrimental to the whole application.

Comment: I can confirm that by reverting to 2.0.0 fixed my problem:
count(ts)
6530
Returned 1 row in 191 ms